# Is VPNService permission dialog by passable?

Tags: android

We are developing a packet capture application in Android using VPNService. Use of VPNService enables a dialog of permission which user has to accept. (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/VpnService). We would like to deploy this app from MDM console, and would like to enforce the use of it. How can we force user to grant the permission? Is there any way the permission is granted during installation time and user will not be shown the dialog.

Comment: Since you NEED permission from the user, the user MUST accept it. It's part of Android's system and you can't avoid that. It's just wrong behavior to not ask your user for permission. The user only needs to allow it once, then you are good to go.

Comment: It would be very problematic if Android allowed this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intent prepare = VpnService.prepare(this);` to check whether the VPN is activated or not, if `prepare` is null, then it's activated, else you should activate it through `startActivityForResult(prepare, REQUEST_VPN);`.
If you want to force the activation then check it in every app launch, or in any activity onResume(), or set an alarm to ask this permission again and again if it's not granted in every VPN activation prompt. Start an activity to enable this VPN service when you receive the alarm.